# Including Bootstrap-like styles with first Angular and LESS app

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, less, bootstrap-5, angular13

I know Bootstrap and some other frameworks related to Angular a bit but am going into first Angular 13 app.

I can see that using LESS is an option which is cool for all the variables and mix-ins and such, but how go I get bootstrap indirectly into my Angular app?

I want it to use on LESS but still having the ability to use things from Bootstrap like spacing and breakpoints and toolitps part of BS 5.1+:

```
pe-3, mb-2, etc.
```

1. Does Bootstrap still using JQuery? (I don't think so but want to be
   sure)
2. Can we use Bootstrap in this way and keep things precompiled
   and fast for downloading the single page application?

Again I am new to Angular and incorporating everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Angular and Bootstrap together I'd recommend making things easier on yourself.

1. Don't use LESS, use SASS -- both Angular and Bootstrap use SASS out of the box, which still gives you variables and other CSS-pre-processor features.
2. Don't mess around with imports yourself, just use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Not only will ng-bootstrap get you all the classes you're familiar with, it also makes a number of more complex components relatively easy.

*Note: if you want Bootstrap 5 you'll need `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@bootstrap5`*

Comment: That looks cool. Do I still need to use SASS to use ng-bootstrap or can I use LESS and still do ng-bootstrap as I don't really want to modify the SASS but use things like tooltips and spacing and grid classes?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use Less but not Sass/SCSS? Bootstrap is [written in Sass] and Angular supports *.scss out of the box. That means down the road you could import and override Bootstrap variables via your top-level or component-level stylesheets, use mix-ins to create new custom classes that follow Bootstrap conventions, etc.

For the most part, Less and Sass provide the same functionality, they just have slightly different syntax (although even that is largely the same at the very basic levels).

  [1]:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/

Comment: It was more of a hypothetical ask as I like LESS and have only used that. I know I can simply use Sass, but if I don't override anything in Bootstrap, is using LESS technically possible?

Comment: Sure. If you want to use ng-bootstrap you can still do that. Or you can just follow the getting started instructions for Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) and add the necessary code directly to your Angular projects index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use bootstrap in the angular application along with your custom LESS code. The easiest way would be to add the CDN links on the [bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/) to the header section in the index.html file in your angular application.

Comment: Yes but is there a way to use Bootstrap without including it that way like someway in angular or LESS?

Comment: You can install bootstrap using npm and update angular.json(styles and scripts array). Starting from bootstrap4, the bootstrap team announced the version 4 alpha which natively uses SASS as a CSS preprocessor. This means there won't be LESS version.